# Easiest way to compute singular values of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ be an invertible matrix. I know $A$ has a singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^T$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $\Sigma$ is diagonal. I call "singular values of $A$" the entries of $\Sigma$. Which is the easiest (meaning less computations where the entries of $A$ are complicated) to compute the singular values of $A$? To me the obvious one is to compute the eigenvalues of $AA^T$, but I was wondering if there is an easier one.

Comment: Are you looking for "efficient" algorithm for SVD?

Comment: Just for the record, the proper spelling of "easyest" is "easiest".

Comment: I would like to compute it by hand so I don't know if algorithms could be good

Comment: Did you check the obvious answer "Wikipedia"? At "calculating the SVD" you'll find some helpful input like "Householder reflections" and "QR decomposition".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indeed need to compute the eigenvalues of $A^TA$.  However, we can compute these eigenvalues *without* computing $A^TA$.

In particular, it suffices to note that
$$
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = \operatorname{trace}(A^TA) = \sum_{i,j=1}^2 a_{ij}^2\\
\lambda_1 \lambda_2 = \det(A^TA) = \det(A)^2
$$
If we call the first number $a$ and the second number $b$, then the eigenvalues are the solutions $\lambda$ to 
$$
\lambda^2 - a\lambda + b = 0
$$
By the quadratic formula, we find that
$$
\lambda_1 = s_1^2 = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}, \qquad \lambda_2 = s_2^2 = \frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}
$$